Missing Google Play Billing v7 javadoc documentation in Android Studio
I'm upgrading the Google Play Billing library from v5 to v7.
After changing the version of com.android.billingclient:billing to 7.0.0 and syncing all dependencies, I noticed that all billing-related documentation was gone.
Instead, I see "Download documentation" option like this:

If I click that option I get immediate build error Task 'ijDownloadSources2b1bf348-4ea' not found in project ':app'. (task name keeps changing)
I've spent so much time googling solutions, but nothing has helped.
How can I bring the documentation back?
